# Is it God’s Spirit The Holy Spirit or another one of God’s spirits? Exodus 28:3

Tags: pneumatology, spiritual-gifts

> “And you shall make holy garments for Aaron your brother, for glory and for beauty. You shall speak to all the skillful, whom I have filled with a **spirit of skill**, that they make Aaron's garments to consecrate him for my priesthood.”
>   ‭‭Exodus‬ ‭28:2-3‬ ‭

Contrast this with

> “”See, I have called by name Bezalel the son of Uri, son of Hur, of the tribe of Judah, and I have filled him with the **Spirit of God**, with ability and intelligence, with knowledge and all craftsmanship... 
>   ...and the finely worked garments, the holy garments for Aaron the priest and the garments of his sons, for their service as priests,”
>   ‭‭Exodus‬ ‭31:2-3, 10‬

When speaking of the seven-fold Spirit of God which is referenced in Revelation 3:1

> “And the Spirit of the Lord shall rest upon him, the Spirit of wisdom and understanding, the Spirit of counsel and might, the Spirit of knowledge and the fear of the Lord.”
>   ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭11:2,3

The spirit of skill is not mentioned here.

Is there reason to believe that this/these spirits are of God but are not The Holy Spirit? And as such the translation should not render it THE Spirit of God but (a) spirit of God was placed over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to suggest that the spirit referenced in places like Ex 28:2, 3, 31:2, 3, 10, Isa 11:2, 3 is anything other than the Holy Spirit and His gifts as discussed at length in the NT.  For example:

> 1 Cor 12:1, 7-11, 28-30 Now about spiritual gifts, brothers, I do not
> want you to be uninformed. ... Now to each one the manifestation of
> the Spirit is given for the common good. 8To one there is given
> through the Spirit the message of wisdom, to another the message of
> knowledge by the same Spirit, to another faith by the same Spirit, to
> another gifts of healing by that one Spirit, to another the working of
> miracles, to another prophecy, to another distinguishing between
> spirits, to another speaking in various tongues, and to still another
> the interpretation of tongues. All these are the work of one and the
> same Spirit, who apportions them to each one as He determines.
>
> And in the church God has appointed first of all apostles, second
> prophets, third teachers, then workers of miracles, and those with
> gifts of healing, helping, administration, and various tongues. Are
> all apostles? Are all prophets? Are all teachers? Do all work
> miracles? Do all have gifts of healing? Do all speak in tongues? Do
> all interpret?

There are more listed in other places such as Eph 4 and Rom 12.  Further, I do not believe that the list of spiritual gifts listed in the NT is intended to be exhaustive.  The Spirit allocates gifts as He determines.  See also 1 Peter 4:10 & 1 Tim 4:14.